# converting mountain standard time to eastern standard time in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a time datetime object.. which has both date and time..

so for example

```
    d = (2011,11,1,8,11,22)  (24 hour time time format)
```

But this time stamp is in mountain standard time.. (Arizona. phoenix)

Now I want to convert this time in EST...

Now that is just the time delta adjustment..

But then there is this daylight saving issues as well.

I was wondering if there is an inbuilt method to take care of daylight saving for adjusting time zones..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library you're looking for is [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic), specifically the localize() method.

Pytz isn't in the standard library but you can get it with pip or easy_install.

Comment: `tz.localize()` converts a naive datetime object in tz to an aware datetime object in tz. It doesn't convert from one timezone to another.

Answer (score 5):

Use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for timezone conversions. pytz takes daylight savings in consideration check [this](http://artofsoftware.org/2012/04/17/dealing-with-daylight-savings-time-using-pytz/). U need a helper function like:

```
def convert(dte, fromZone, toZone):
    fromZone, toZone = pytz.timezone(fromZone), pytz.timezone(toZone)
    return fromZone.localize(dte, is_dst=True).astimezone(toZone)
```

Comment: `toZone.normalize()` call might be missing. `is_dst=True` is wrong 50% of the time during DST transitions

Answer (score 1):

Based on example in the [`pytz` docs](http://pytz.sf.net) that converts a naive datetime object from one timezone to another:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def convert(naive_dt, from_tz, to_tz, is_dst=None):
    """Convert naive_dt from from_tz timezone to to_tz timezone.

    if is_dst is None then it raises an exception for ambiguous times
    e.g., 2002-10-27 01:30:00 in US/Eastern
    """
    from_dt = from_tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=is_dst)
    return to_tz.normalize(from_dt.astimezone(to_tz))

ph_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Phoenix')
east_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
from_naive_dt = datetime(2011, 11, 1, 8, 11, 22)
east_dt = convert(from_naive_dt, ph_tz, east_tz)

def p(dt):
    print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))

p(east_dt)  # -> 2011-11-01 11:11:22 EDT-0400
```

Here's an example of ambiguous time from the pytz docs:

```
ambiguous_dt = datetime(2002, 10, 27, 1, 30)
p(convert(ambiguous_dt, east_tz, pytz.utc, is_dst=True))
p(convert(ambiguous_dt, east_tz, pytz.utc, is_dst=False))
p(convert(ambiguous_dt, east_tz, pytz.utc, is_dst=None)) # raise exception
assert 0 # unreachable
```

Output:

```
2002-10-27 05:30:00 UTC+0000 # ambiguous_dt is interpreted as EDT-0400
2002-10-27 06:30:00 UTC+0000 # ambiguous_dt is interpreted as EST-0500
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2002-10-27 01:30:00
```